# Computed (NSObject) Properties in SwiftUI don't update the view

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, computed-properties, combine

So, I want to have a `Text` that changes its content based on the contents of my CoreData Model. To do that I used a computed property in Xcode beta 4 but it doesn't seem to work anymore. Either that's a bug or there is some other issue I don't see?

The problem I have exactly is that my View (and the computed property) don't seem to get updated when `self.objectWillChange.send()` is called in my store.

I also tried to 'export' my var into the store and get it from there, with the same result...

---

**EDIT:**
I just tried the same with another class and it didn't work with just `objectWillChange.send()` but only with `@Published` however, even that stopped working if the class inherited from NSObject...

---

I just found out: with

```swift
struct Today: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var myStore: DateStore
    var hasPlans: Bool {
        guard let plans = myStore.getPlans() else { return false }
        return plans.isEmpty
    }

    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text(hasPlans ? "I have plans":"I have time today")
            Button(action: {
                self.myStore.addPlans(for: Date())
            }) {
                Text("I have plans")
            }
    }
}

class DateStore: NSObject, ObservableObject, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    private var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<DateStore>
    //...
    public func addPlans(for date: Date){
        //{...}
        if let day = self.dates.first(where: { $0.date == date}){
            day.plans += 1
            saveChanges()
        }else{
            self.create(date: dayDate)
        }
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        self.objectWillChange.send()
    }
}
```

That's a very simplified version of my problem and I know that my DataModel works because the values change and `self.objectWillChange.send()` is called, but my View isn't updated for some reason....

Comment: Did you account for the Beta 5 changes? https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-changes-in-xcode-11-beta-5

Comment: Yes, I removed all deprecated methods and changed everything to ObservableObjects as you also see in my code.. but I didn't find anything about what changed in computed properties or how the View gets updated....

Comment: Confirming that I'm seeing the same problem.

Comment: I don't see your implementation of `objectWillChange`.

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue with when I have a subclass of a class conforming to @ObservableObject. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57615920/4116421)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see that NSObject is the source of the problem. The problem seems to be that you haven't implemented `objectWillChange`. The compiler will let you get away with that, but the result is that your `objectWillChange` does nothing.

Here's a simple example that shows how to configure an ObservableObject (that is an NSObject) with a computed property whose binding works:

```
class Thing : NSObject, ObservableObject {
    let objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()
    var computedProperty : Bool = true {
        willSet {
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var thing : Thing
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(self.thing.computedProperty ? "Hello" : "Goodbye") {
                self.thing.computedProperty.toggle()
            }
            Toggle.init("", isOn: self.$thing.computedProperty).frame(width:0)
        }
    }
}
```

You can see by tapping the button and the switch that everything is live and responsive to the binding within the view.

Comment: But maybe I've misunderstood the question? Is it about your `hasPlans`? So you expect it to magically recalculate itself? In that case, yes, you'd need your own publisher and your own subscription; only inside a `body` do you get automatic recalculation when a binding changes.

Answer (score 3):

Experimenting with my own code exhibiting similar problem.

It looks like the @Publisher SwiftUI magic breaks when the Class adopting ObservableObject is a subclass of NSObject.

The short answer solution is that if you can get it working with @Published when it is not a subclass of NSObject, then when you make it a subclass of NSObject, replace @Published with

```
let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
```

You'll have to import the Combine framework in your Class file to do this.

Here is some code from the working app I'm experimenting with.

The View:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    //Bind using @ObservedObject
    @ObservedObject var provider: Provider

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(self.provider.distance)")
    }
    ...
}
```

The Class:

```
import Combine

class Provider: NSObject, ObservableObject {

    //Instead of using @Published, use objectwillchange
    //@Published var distance: CLLocationDistance = 0.0
    let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    var distance = 0.0
    ...

    func calculateDistance() {
        ...
        // publish the change
        self.objectWillChange.send()
        self.distance = newDistance
    }
}
```

Comment: how is calculateDistance() called?

Answer (score 1):

One solution that is working is to simply make a *new* `@State var` instead of using the computed property. However, according WWDC talks about SwiftUI this feels somewhat wrong because my 'actual state' is living in my data model and by declaring a new `@State` I need to keep both of them in sync which is against the "Single Source of Truth" pattern isn't it?