# SwiftUI - ObservableObject that inherits from NSObject does not update in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, observableobject

I know, this is one of those "Not working in iOS XX" questions, but I'm completely stuck...

So I have an `ObservableObject` class that inherits from `NSObject`, because I need to listen to the delegate methods of `UISearchResultsUpdating`.

```
class SearchBarListener: NSObject, UISearchResultsUpdating, ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var searchText: String = ""
    let searchController: UISearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    }
    
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        
        /// Publish search bar text changes
        if let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text {
            print("text: \(searchBarText)")
            self.searchText = searchBarText
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var searchBar = SearchBarListener()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Search text: \(searchBar.searchText)")
        .padding()

        /// more code that's not related 
    }
}
```

The problem is that even though `print("text: \(searchBarText)")` prints fine, the `Text("Search text: \(searchBar.searchText)")` **is never updated** (in iOS 13). It works fine in iOS 14.

---

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
class SearchBarTester: NSObject, ObservableObject {

    @Published var searchText: String = ""

    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
            print("updated")
            self.searchText = "Updated"
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var searchBar = SearchBarTester()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Search text: \(searchBar.searchText)")
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

After 5 seconds, "updated" is printed in the console, but the `Text` doesn't change. In iOS 14, the `Text` changes to **"Search text: Updated"** as expected.

<kbd>[image: "Updated" printed in console but simulator does not change]</kbd>

However, if I don't inherit from `NSObject`, **both** iOS 13 and iOS 14 work!

```
class SearchBarTester: ObservableObject {

    @Published var searchText: String = ""

    init() {
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
            print("updated")
            self.searchText = "Updated"
        }
    }
}
```

<kbd>[image: "Updated" printed in console and simulator also changes]</kbd>

I think the problem has something to do with inheriting from a class. Maybe it's something that was fixed in iOS 14. But does anyone know what is going on?

---

#### Edit

Thanks [@Cuneyt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2739567/) for the answer! Here's the code that finally worked:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine /// make sure to import this

class SearchBarTester: NSObject, ObservableObject {

    let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    @Published var searchText: String = "" {
        willSet {
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
            print("updated")
            self.searchText = "Updated"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Can you specify the iOS versions please? (i.e 13.x.x & 14.x.x)

Comment: I tested on 13.0 and 14.0.

Comment: Please don’t edit the answer into the question, the answers section is for that

Comment: @Cristik this was only because the answer didn't specify where to define `objectWillChange` and the `import Combine`, so I thought it would be more clear... but I'll keep in mind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be on iOS 13, if you subclass an object and do not conform to `ObservableObject` directly (as in `class SearchBarTester: ObservableObject`), you'll need to add this boilerplate code:

```
@Published var searchText: String = "" {
    willSet {
        objectWillChange.send()
    }
}
```

However, calling the default `objectWillChange` will still not work, hence you'll need to define it yourself again:

```
let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But it didn't work... I actually already tried this solution from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62192636/14351818)

Comment: Sorry about that! I am just downloading iOS 13.0 simulators, will update my answer accordingly later.

Comment: Found a solution :) Please have a look. I am not sure how it works this way though, SwiftUI and Combine are complicated sometimes!